# Problem with std::map and std::pair

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, stdmap, std-pair

I have a small program I want to execute to test something

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct _pos{
        float xi;
        float xf;

        bool operator<(_pos& other){

                return this->xi < other.xi;
        }
};

struct _val{

        float f;
};

int main()
{
        map<_pos,_val> m;

        struct  _pos k1 = {0,10};
        struct  _pos k2 = {10,15};

        struct  _val v1 = {5.5};
        struct  _val v2 = {12.3};                                                                   

        m.insert(std::pair<_pos,_val>(k1,v1));
        m.insert(std::pair<_pos,_val>(k2,v2));

        return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to compile it, I get the following error

```
$ g++ m2.cpp -o mtest
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/map:60,
                 from m2.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = _pos]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:1170:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = _pos, _Val = std::pair<const _pos, _val>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _pos, _val> >, _Compare = std::less<_pos>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const _pos, _val> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:500:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>&) [with _Key = _pos, _Tp = _val, _Compare = std::less<_pos>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const _pos, _val> >]’
m2.cpp:30:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_function.h:230: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
m2.cpp:9: note: candidates are: bool _pos::operator<(_pos&)
$
```

I thought that declaring the operator< on the key would solve the problem, but its still there.

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In C++ all identifiers that start with a double underscore, a single underscore followed by a capital letter or a single underscore followed by a lowercase letter in the global namespace are reserved for the implementation. The identifiers `_pos` and `_val` should be changed.

Comment: @David Rodríguez. Thanks, will do and keep that in mind.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
bool operator<(_pos& other)
```

Should be this:

```
bool operator<(const _pos& other) const {
//             ^^^^               ^^^^^
```

Without the first `const`, the right-hand side of the comparison (`b` in `a < b`) cannot be `const`, since without `const` the function may modify its argument.

Without the second `const`, the left-hand side of the comparison (`a` in `a < b`) cannot be `const`, since without `const` the function may modify `this`.

Internally, the key's of a map are always `const`.

---

It should be noted that you should prefer to use nonmember functions. That is, better is a free-function:

```
bool operator<(const _pos& lhs, const _pos& rhs)
{
    return lhs.xi < rhs.xi;
}
```

In the same namespace as your class. (For our example, just underneath it.)

---

By the way, in C++ there is no need to prefix the declaration of a struct type variable with `struct`. This is perfect, and preferred:

```
    _pos k1 = {0,10};
    _pos k2 = {10,15};

    _val v1 = {5.5};
    _val v2 = {12.3};
```

(Though your type names are admittedly named in an unorthodox manner. :P)

---

Lastly, you should prefer the `make_pair` utility function for making pairs:

```
    m.insert(std::make_pair(k1,v1));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(k2,v2));
```

It saves you from having to write out the types for the pair, and is generally easier to read. (Especially when longer type names come along.)

Comment: @Tom: No problem, I've added more. :P

Comment: In this case, subscript notation is probably neater than using insert directly: `m[k1]=v1; m[k2]=v2;`.

Comment: I would note that the subscript operator and the insert operation have different semantics in case the element is already present: subscript replaces it while insert does not. *They are not interchangeable* in general! Also, insert works with other containers (`set` for example) while the subscript operator is very specific to associative containers like `map`.

Answer (score 5):

Signature of the less than operator needs to be `bool operator<(const _pos& other) const`, otherwise map can not use this operator in const functions since this member function is declared as non-const.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your definition of operator< is wrong - the right hand side (argument in this case) should be marked const and it should be a const member function, e.g.

```
    bool operator<(const _pos& other) const{ 

            return this->xi < other.xi; 
    }
```